# Highcharts show loading icon when fetching data in javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts, loader

We want to show loading icon when the data loads and chart is made in highcharts.

Below is pseudo code:

```
// service call
// data is pushed in data set 
// and that data is used in highcharts.

$('Chart_name').highcharts({
});
```

Comment: What is the problem then?

Comment: Please explain what you have tried, what you are expecting, if you have read the handbook.

Comment: You can set background image - see the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690401/highcharts-loading-image), read API for other options http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/loading - example http://jsfiddle.net/86nuH/127/

Answer (score 5):

Render chart without data, then show loading screen, fetch data, hide loading screen.

Example:

```
// Options without data
const options = {
  series: [{
    data: [],
    type: 'column'
  }]
}

// Redner chart
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options)

// Simulate fetch request timeout, get data after some delay
setTimeout(() => {
  const data = [1,2,3]
  chart.hideLoading()
  chart.series[0].setData(data)
}, 2000)

// Show loading screen
chart.showLoading()
```

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/hLj1advd/